# How to connect to xrdp Server from fedora 13

Tags: fedora, remote-desktop, xrdp

I have a Fedora PC in which xrdp server is installed . I could able to connect from Windows-7 to that Fedora PC. How can I connect from Another Fedora PC?(Fedora 13)

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing Remmina (Remote desktop client for Linux-based operating systems)
http://remmina.sourceforge.net

command executed

```
# yum install remmina
```

And it Worked Fine..